# Pointers to class of root type in C#

Tags: c#, class, pointers

I'm sorta new to C# and don't know how to implement pointer interfaces for class types that I am defining. Its super easy to do in C++ (though, I've not done it since college) or C (where I do it all the time), but I'm having trouble not getting errors in C#.

Its clearer in example. Suppose you want to implement a family tree:

```
class person{
   person* mom;
   person* dad;
   string Name;
   string Birthdate;     

   person[] children;


//...constructors, destructors, methods etc...
}
```

VS2010 Tells me that "Cannot declare a pointer to a managed type"
I don't want to know of good implementations for this kind of problem (since I will be making the structure pretty custom and not anything at all like a tree), just how to declare pointers to objects of the type that contains the pointer (in C#)
Is this the wrong way to use a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to declare them as pointers, just as the type:

```
class person{
   person mom;
   person dad;
   string Name;
   string Birthdate;     

   // Though I would probably use ICollection<Person> or IList<person>
   person[] children;

   //...constructors, destructors, methods etc...
}
```

Since `person` is a [reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx), that's all you need.

In general, pointers are not needed in c# (though you can use them in code marked as `unsafe`).

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks for the tips on other reference types and the collections (that preempts the other question that I was writing).

Answer (score 3):

Remove the pointers and your code will work fine. In C#, classes already are references, there is no such thing as a value `class`, that construct is called `struct`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer, since a struct is really not a type. In C I might use a typedef struct to accomplish the recursive definition of the type, but I don't know how you'd do the typedef in C#.

Comment: C#'s `struct` is the equivalent of a stack-allocated object in C, whereas C#'s `class` is the equivalent of a heap-allocated object in C. `class` would be closer to a double pointer actually, where `person` in C# is kind of like `person **` in C.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a variable of a `class` type it's automatically a reference. A reference in C# behaves pretty much like a pointer in C++, except that you can't do arithmetic with it.

Unlike C++ you don't decide to use references/values when you declare a variable, but when you declare a type. Being a reference or a valuetype is an inherent property of a type.

Answer (score 0):

C# code does not use pointers. While it's possible to write C# that makes use of pointers, this code is called "unsafe" and there is very little, if any, reason to use this feature in ordinary code.

All classes in any of the .NET languages are called "reference types". This means that wherever you see that type used in code for a variable, member, or parameter type, then the value of that object is a *reference* that (for lack of a better term) points to an *instance* of the type. In other words, they function in very similar fashion to pointers, though only in the most basic sense (there is no such thing as "reference arithmetic", for example).

To make a long story short, simply remove the asterisk from your declarations and your code will work how you originally intended for it to. While there are some stylistic issues with your code (.NET code is conventionally PascalCased, not camelCased, and it's best not to expose member variables directly, but rather use properties), that should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm...you don't need pointers on C# (to do this). If your intent is to create a "tree", just remove the "*" sign in front of the type name.

hope it helps.